# XAMARIN - not found in xmlns clr-namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i'm new with Xamarin, i tried to open the simulator iOS but i found this error:

> Position 9:14. Type infra:IstanceLocator not found in xmlns
>   clr-namespace:Convert.Infrastructure;assembly=Convert

**MY PROJECT**

https://snag.gy/98ygVu.jpg

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:infra="clr-namespace:Convert.Infrastructure;assembly=Convert"
    x:Class="Convert.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <infra:IstanceLocator x:Key="Locator"></infra:IstanceLocator>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Convert.Pages;

namespace Convert
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

**IstanceLocator.cs**

```
using System;
using Convert.ViewModels;
namespace Convert.Infrastructure
{
    public class InstanceLocator
    {
        public MainViewModel Main { get; set; }

        public InstanceLocator()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo

```
<infra:IstanceLocator x:Key="Locator"></infra:IstanceLocator>
```

You're missing the "n" in InstanceLocator